# packages url Ubuntu12.04 armhf

Tags: ros, ubuntu, update, ubuntu-precise, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

While running apt-get update on Ubuntu12.04, the error

Err http://packages.namniart.com precise Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'packages.namniart.com'
Fetched 2,855 kB in 30s (94.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'packages.namniart.com'

was given, while packages.namniart.com is reachable. Any idea ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142451/packages-url-ubuntu12.04-armhf/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you have a network or DNS problem.

Can you ping packages.namniart.com from your board? If that doesn't work, can you ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-20**:
Yes, I can ping both from the board.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-20**:
Try again and see if it was a fluke? Otherwise this sounds like it's an issue specific to apt.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-20**:
I tried three times, both namniart and google. All pings work. Remarkable is that apt-get install start well and downloads the package, but stalls after that. Even kill -9 doesn't kill it. The failure of roscore (my original problem) has nothing to do with apt or Ubuntu, right ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-20**:
I suspect they're both symptoms of the same underlying problem. Perhaps the disk is full? Have you looked at the kernel logs at all?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-20**:
Could be. Disk is at 57%, so no problem there. Kernel logs show nothing wrong so far. Will check further.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-25**:
Reading this in the log:

[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-03-26 10:13:51,179: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-03-26 10:13:51,182: Started XML-RPC server [http://BBxM:48536/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-03-26 10:13:51,184: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server

Is this correct ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-26**:
Does the hostname BBxM resolve on you machine? What IP address does it resolve to?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-26**:
Yes it does. ping BBxM resolves to 127.0.1.1 which is set in /etc/hosts.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-04-01**:
I was suggested to test ROS Indigo to see if that would work better, but when looking for it, I think it's not even available for armhf yet. Apart from that, I doubt it's even compatible with Ubuntu Precise. Or is it ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-02**:
There are no armhf debs for Indigo yet; sorry. Indigo is also not supported on Ubuntu versions before 13.10.